# Proving a linear transformation that preserves the inner product is an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry, inner-products, isometry

I am currently working on a problem to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation. Prove that $T$ is an isometry if and only if $T(v) \cdot T(w) = v \cdot w$

I've already written up a proof for the reverse statement (assuming $T$ is an isometry and showing it preserves the inner product) and now I need to prove the forward statement (assuming $T$ preserves the inner product and showing that it must be an isometry). I know this problem has, essentially, $2$ parts:

1. Showing that the requirement of an isometry $\lvert T(v)-T(w) \rvert = \lvert v-w \rvert$ follows from the assumption that $T(v) \cdot T(w) = v \cdot w$, where $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$
2. Proving that $T$ is a bijection. Since an isometry is a bijection that preserves distance.

I have a quick draft of a proof for part $1$ that I will write down below, that I believe is on the right track, but more than likely needs some work. For part $2$ I'm struggling to see how the condition that $T$ preserves inner product necessitates it be injective and surjective.

---

**Work for part $1$:**

Assume $T(v) \cdot T(w) = v \cdot w, \forall v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since vector spaces are closed under addition and additive inverses we can say that
$$T(v)-T(w) \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ $$v-w \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
Thus from our assumption we have
$$[T(v)-T(w)] \cdot [T(v)-T(w)] = [v-w] \cdot [v-w]$$
Taking the square root of both sides we have
$$ \lvert T(v)-T(w) \rvert = \sqrt{[T(v)-T(w)] \cdot [T(v)-T(w)]} = \sqrt{[v-w] \cdot [v-w]} = \lvert v-w \rvert$$

Which is exactly the requirement for a linear transformation to be an isometry.

---

**Proving $T$ is a bijection**

Now this part I seem to be struggling just getting started, so any guidance in that regard is much appreciated. I have collected some of the relevant facts and have been looking at them trying to see how it all comes together. I shall list them below:

1. $T(av) = aT(v)$, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n$
2. $T(v+w) = T(v) + T(w)$ $\forall v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$
3. $T(v) \cdot T(w) = v \cdot w$

As previously mentioned I'm having trouble, specifically, seeing how property $3$ contributes to the requirement that $T$ is a bijection.

Comment: If $T(v)=0$, so that $T(v)\cdot T(v)=0$, then...

Comment: @Joe Then $v \cdot v = 0$ and hence $v = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Joe, Okay so are you saying to apply this principle more generally to show injectivity of $T$? If so, then since inner products have the property of positive definiteness then wouldn't there be the case that a negative vector would give the same result as the positive version. E.g., $$T(v) = (-1, -1, -1)$$ so that $$T(v) \cdot T(v) = 3$$ but we could have $$v = (1, 1, 1)$$ so that $$v \cdot v = 3$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. We just showed that $T(v)=0 \implies v=0$, so $T$ is injective. Then, since $T$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, it is also surjective.

Comment: @Joe My apologies, to my mind, it just seemed like we were showing the injectivity requirement for only one value, namely $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ when injectivity is a general requirement for all $T(v),v \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, for a linear transformation, $T(v_1)=T(v_2) \implies T(v_1 - v_2) = 0$. So if the null space is $\{0\}$, then the map is injective. Then we use the rank nullity theorem to deduce that it is surjective.

Comment: @Joe Could you explain, without reference to the Rank Nullity Theorem how one might deduce that $T$ is surjective? 

I only ask because for the course I am taking, I am not sure what is or isn't "allowed" to use and, given that we had a review section of linear algebra that made no mention of that theorem, nor null space (really just vector (sub)spaces, linear transforms, matrix representations, linear independence, spanning, bases, the general linear group and determinants) I was hoping to maybe gain some intuition that is tied solely to "usable" information.

Comment: If you have $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, then by linearity$$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i T(v_i) = ?$$You can use that (and the fact that $T$ is injective) to show that the image of $T$ has dimension $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\Vert Tx\right\Vert ^{2}=\left\langle Tx,Tx\right\rangle =\left\langle x,x\right\rangle =\left\Vert x\right\Vert ^{2}$$

Comment: The supposition that $$T(v) \cdot T(v) = v \cdot v$$ could imply that $$T(v) = \pm v$$ though, couldn't it? 

Since $$T(v) \cdot T(v) = T(v_{1})^{2} + \cdots + T(v_{n})^{2}$$ and $$ (v_{i})^{2} = (-v_{i})^{2}$$

Comment: @NumericalDisintegration, $T(v)\cdot T(v) = v \cdot v$ could have ***many*** more solutions that just $T(v)=v$ or $T(v)=-v$. Simply consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $T$ equal to any rotation. However, if you're questioning whether or not $T$ is injective, you want to see if you can show that $T(v_1) = T(v_2) \implies v_1 = v_2$, ***not*** whether there is only one possible image of $v$ under $T$.